# Web Browser for Large Screen

Tags: software-recommendation

I have a Mythbuntu media center set up being displayed on a 42" screen. I have chromium as the browser, and you cannot browse from the couch because the address bar as the icons are very small. Does anyone know of a web browser that works in Ubuntu that is designed for a large display? Thanks.

Comment: Set up Firefox to use Bigger Icons. Chrome/Chromium doesn't allow to Customize the Toolbar.

Comment: try also epiphany or even konqueror

Comment: I'll try both of those, once I get an active internet connection to the device. Currently trying to get Kaffine to work with the system font size, as everything is all tiny.

Comment: What is the reasoning behind the downvote? It is a perfectly legitimate question.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember well, Mythbuntu uses GNOME desktop. You can install gnome-tweak-tool from repo which enables you to scale text. May be useful for you, I use it to scale down text on netbook.

**Be aware**: in Chrome/Chromium it works on bars, but NOT content.

Comment: Nope, Mythbuntu uses XFCE. I already used the dedicated XFCE settings application and changed the font size. However, chromium does not allow me to change the toolbar, as stated in a comment above. So I'll have to try an alternative browser.

Comment: Maybe try this: [link](http://xubuntu.wordpress.com/2006/08/09/howto-fix-xfce-fonts/). This is a text on how to change DPI in XFCE.

Comment: Already changed it. Been there, done that. It's just that chromium is ignoring the changes.